# SaltStack: Use Temporary Scripts And Not Cause State Changes To Reported

Tags: salt

I am doing some operations with Kafka via salt, and using scripts to perform them.

My current SLS file looks roughly like:

```
/tmp/script.sh:
  file.managed:
    - source: salt://blah/blah

Run script:
  cmd.run:
    - name: /tmp/script.sh

delete /tmp/script.sh:
  file.absent
    - name: /tmp/script.sh
```

`script.sh` is idempotent itself. But I always get a `changed=2` status report at the end of applying the state, because of it putting the script down and then deleting it.

Is there a more idiomatic way in Salt to have temporary scripts that don't live on the target box? Or do people usually just leave them in /tmp so that they don't see a reported change when applying a state.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to consider adding an [`unless` or `onlyif`](https://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/ref/states/requisites.html#unless) requisite in the first directive - especially if script.sh is particularly complicated or expensive. With `unless` or `onlyif`, you will use the reults of several BASH commands to determine if you need to push down and execute your script. If your system is out of plumb only then is the state enforced. If everything checks out OK, then the script will never be pushed and executed preventing `changed=2` in the final status report. You will want to use a [require](https://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/ref/states/requisites.html#require) requisite for the second and third directives to prevent them from running if the script is not pushed by `file.managed` otherwise you will get to errors instead of two changes.